# Создание сайта с PHP

Tags: php

Я всегда создавал сайты с HTML CSS т.д. Мне мой знакомый сказал есть сайт надо внести изменение я сказал сделаю ну передо мной есть такая тема.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а в content [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так после я зашел в themes и там я вижу footer.php page.php index.php. Я подумал html css изменить ну понятно а перед мною

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="col-md-12 breadcrumbs-wrapper">

<div class="breadcrumbs container">

    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))

    {

        bcn_display();

    }?>

</div>

</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-9" id="content">

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="media" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <?php

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>

        <a class="media-left" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'thumbnail img-responsive')); ?>

        </a>

        <?php }

        else {}

        ?>

        <div class="media-body">

        <h4 class="media-heading" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a>

        </h4>

        <ul class="meta">

        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></li>

        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></li>

        <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><?php comments_number( '0 şərh', '1 şərh', '% şərh' ); ?></li>

        </ul>

        <span style="font-size:14px;" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); echo mb_substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,300).'&nbsp;[...]'; ?></span>

        </div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_pagenavi();?>

<?php else :?>

<?php endif; ?> 

</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Это что такое и как изменить сайт. Помогите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это CMS "Wordpress".

Официальный сайт: https://ru.wordpress.org/

Так просто с лёту Вы там ничего не сможете изменить. Нужен опыт работы с CMS и с водпресс в частности.

Comment: Тогда как изменить контент сайта с Wordpress?

Comment: Контент хранится в базе и меняется из админки сайта http://[название сайта]/wp-admin

Comment: Я вам блогадарен! Последний вопрос откуда можно узнать пароль и логин для wp-admin

Comment: @SportsTubers нигде, пароль зашифрован в базе. Только у владельца сайта, ну или добавить себя админом посредством кода.

Comment: От того кто дал вам сайт для доработок очевидно.

Comment: У меня тут есть пароль от cpanel а нету что то подобное с wordpress а с помощью кода как можно? тут я вижу wp-admin admin.php т.д

Comment: это уже совсем другой вопрос. создайте новый вопрос или поищите в гугле

Comment: понятно блогадарен вам !